# Adding different label legends to the right side of a barplot without changing original data

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my data I have `var1` whose type is character and values are "01", "02" and so on. I want to create a barplot showing the frequencies of `var1` values. In the x-axis should be "01", "02" etc., but not "Type 1", "Type 2" etc. Also, I want label legends as a list to the right side of the plot, showing that 01 = Type 1, 02 = Type 2, and so on. How to do this without changing any values in the original data?

Could `value_labels` concatenation and converting `var1` into factor be useful in this?

Like this:

```
value_labels <- c("01" = "Type", "02" = "Type 2", "03" = "Type 3")

# Convert var1 to a factor with custom labels
df$var1 <- factor(df$var1, levels = names(value_labels), labels = value_labels)
```

And then use `value_labels` only when adding the label legends to basic barplot?

Thus far my plot looks like this:
[image]

Code

```
value_labels <- c("01" = "Type", "02" = "Type 2", "03" = "Type 3")

# Convert var1 to a factor with custom labels
df$var1 <- factor(df$var1, levels = names(value_labels), labels = value_labels)

# Create a bar plot
ggplot(forest, aes(x = var1)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title = "Frequency of var1",
       x = "Categories",
       y = "Frequency")
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this? Are you trying to save space on your x axis? Why do you want to avoid changing the underlying data frame?

Comment: I want to avoid text strings on the x-axis because it would be very messy with the real meaning of the categories, too long words

Comment: Why not avoid a legend, but instead set `xlab("Type")` - then it should be clear that each number on the x axis corresponds to a type number.

Answer (score 1):

You could annotate your plot with a table, in place of a legend.

[image]

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

#### Create a data set

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c('01','02','03'), 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.45, 0.20, 0.35)))
```

#### Make a table with the variables and lables

```
df_labels <- data.frame(
  var1 = c('01','02','03'),
  label = c('Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type3')
)

table_theme <- gridExtra::ttheme_default(
  core = list(padding = unit(c(2.5, 2.5), "mm")))

label_table <- tableGrob(df_labels, theme = table_theme, rows = NULL)
```

#### Construct the plot

```
p1 <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var1)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = df_labels$label) +
  labs(title = "Frequency of var1",
       x = "Categories",
       y = "Frequency") 

grid.arrange(p1, label_table, nrow = 1, as.table = TRUE, widths = c(4,1))
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Seth. Your solution is pretty much what I was looking for. Only the label legends do not like neat, and on the x-axis there should be the number codes, not strings

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by passing a function to the `label` argument of `scale_x_discrete` that transforms your label into a new label:

```r
library(stringr)

change_label <- function(x){

  new_label <- str_extract(x, "\\d+")
  
  # Add single trailing zero
  new_label[nchar(new_label) < 2] <- 
    str_c("0", new_label[nchar(new_label) < 2])
}

ggplot(forest, aes(x = var1)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title = "Frequency of var1",
       x = "Categories",
       y = "Frequency") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = change_label)
```

The only way I can think to add a legend that decodes your x-axis label would be to use `scale_fill_manual()` in conjuction with a `aes(fill = "foo")`, then use the fill scale to show the key for your x axis. This is ill advised - it will be difficult to do and unclear to the reader.

Comment: your code only produces an error message, some issue with ```}```

Comment: Thanks @Espejito - it was a missing `)`. I've fixed it now.